# Wrong u128 multiplication in Rust?

Tags: rust

Before I open bug, I want to check what is going on here.

I'm porting this C-code here to Rust:

```
    unsigned __int128 r = (unsigned __int128)a * (unsigned __int128)b;
```

easy enough (I thought):

```
    let r = (a as u128) * (b as u128);
```

Now with this input parameters I get a different multiplication result in C and Rust:

```
(0x56eaa5f5f650a9e3 as u128) * (0xa0cf24341e75bda9 as u128)
```

The results are different in Rust and C:

```
Rust: 0x3698fbc09d2c5b15e8889b1b676bbddb
C:    0x3698fbc0f417010bded944fe676bbddb
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I [cross-checked the result](https://www.miniwebtool.com/hex-calculator/?number1=56eaa5f5f650a9e3&operate=3&number2=a0cf24351e75bda9), and got the same result as the C code.

Am I missing something?

=== context information added:

It is this function from xmr-stak (https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak) thas is behaving differently:

```
static inline uint64_t _umul128(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t* hi)
{
    unsigned __int128 r = (unsigned __int128)a * (unsigned __int128)b;
    *hi = r >> 64;
    return (uint64_t)r;
}
```

Regardless if the C implementation is wrong, I have to recreate the exact computation in Rust, because this is needed for a hash computation.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your C code rather. Python `>>> hex(0x56eaa5f5f650a9e3 * 0xa0cf24341e75bda9)                                                                            
'0x3698fbc09d2c5b15e8889b1b676bbddb'` and wolfram alpha agree with the rust result [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0x56eaa5f5f650a9e3+*+0xa0cf24341e75bda9+in+hex) Can you show the whole C code as well.

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE] (in particular *complete* and *verifiable*) for the Rust *and* the C code? I also think the error is in your C code as Rust's result seems to be correct.

Comment: `>>> hex(0x3698fbc09d2c5b15e8889b1b676bbddb//0x56eaa5f5f650a9e3)`

`'0xa0cf24341e75bda9'`

`>>> hex(0x3698fbc0f417010bded944fe676bbddb//0x56eaa5f5f650a9e3)`

`'0xa0cf24351e75bda9'`

Looks like you made a typo

Answer (score 7):

I looks like you must have a made a typo in either language:

```py
>>> hex(0x3698fbc09d2c5b15e8889b1b676bbddb//0x56eaa5f5f650a9e3)
'0xa0cf24341e75bda9' # what your Rust code uses
>>> hex(0x3698fbc0f417010bded944fe676bbddb//0x56eaa5f5f650a9e3)
'0xa0cf24351e75bda9' # what your online calculator uses
          ^
```

Classical case of off-by-0x100000000 error :)

Comment: year, you are right, the input is different. I starred a the hashes for hours and didn't see any difference!